# EF Many to many relationship with additional properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, partial-classes

I know that this is a repeated question and I know that this is not possible if there are additional properties in the "in the middle" table.

I had an idea how to get the effect of an m:N relationship instead of an 1:n-n-1, but I'd like to hear some other thoughts.

If I have three entities, A, B, and AB where AB makes the A:B relation possible and it has additional properties.

Using Databasefirst approach, I thought to make a partial class of A and B.

```
public partial Class A
{
    public IEnumerable<EntityObject> Bs 
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Select(p=>p.AB.B);
        }
        set { //... }
    }
}
```

Could something like this be possible.

Just doodling in my head. I am currently on vacation and have no computer, so this is not tested but just written on my cell phone.

I see that this could be a problem after context disposing or detaching, also with including in an eager loading approach.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Why don't you decompose the many-to-many you get automatically via having `ICollection` in each entity and create your own middle entity that has a straight reference to each of the other entities plus the extra properties? I was doing this just for m-2-m before I realised that EF could do it for you.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I am currently having the A-AB-B entities. Could you please explain more in detail what you mean

Comment: You can manually define the AB entity, which happens to have a single reference to A and B (thus generating the m-2-m). A will have a list of AB, and B will have a list of AB. Then you can put what you like on AB as you are in control of the entity. This is from a code-first perspective.

Comment: Noooo, you understoood me wrong. I would like to have in A a collection of B, and in B a collection of A. I have nothing against AB, but I would like to use it as a proxy in order to have a behavior in A and B just like there would not B an AB table. I am using an AB entity

Comment: Correct me if I misinterpreted your question, but the closest analog I can think of is the `has_many B, :through => [AB]` syntax in Rails. In the case of EF, join tables with extra "payload" are not supported in a many-to-many relationship, so you'll need to manually handle AB as it seems you are doing. From there, it's simply a matter of getting the right LINQ query to select all B across AB. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: Exactly my point Smudge. I know that if there are additional tables in the AB table it will be mapped as an entity.
I am thinking of surpassing this limitation by keeping the AB entity in the model.
Since the Entitie are classes, I thought myself to extend the entity with a partial class and in this extension I could  mimic the way it works as if would if there would not be additional properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are already treating AB as a distinct entity, then to get all B from A all you need is something like this:

```
public partial class A
{
    public IQueryable<B> Bs {
        get { return this.ABs.AsQueryable().Select(ab => ab.B).Distinct(); }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure how well this will perform, as compared to a built-in Many-To-Many supported by EF (without any payload), but it will give you what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

If technically possible or not, expressing such a relationship with "*additional properties in the in the middle table*" as many-to-many relationship is just wrong because it hides that the "middle table" has a business meaning and therefore must be an entity on its own.

A somewhat classical example for such a model are `RawMaterial` and `Product`: A `RawMaterial` can be used in multiple `Product`s and a `Product` can be made of multiple `RawMaterial`s. The entity in between - maybe called `RecipePart` - contains a `Quantity` how many pieces of a given `RawMaterial` are used in a given `Product`.

If you have for example the product `ChocolateBar` and work with its relation to raw materials you will deal with a recipe that says a `ChocolateBar` has 60 units of `Chocolate` and 40 units of `Milk`, i.e. `ChocolateBar` has a collection of `RecipePart`s and every `RecipePart` describes the quantity and refers to the related `RawMaterial`. A `ChocolateBar` does *not* have a direct collection of `RawMaterial`s in this business model.

For a particular query (maybe some statistics) you might be only interested in its raw materials - a chocolate bar is made if chocolate and milk, no matter how many units - but that is a special query in your business model and kind of an aggregation that ignores some pieces of the full detailed model information. This is what your helper property `this.Select(p=>p.AB.B);` does: It does not express the full relationship but is a specialized query that says: Give me only the `RawMaterial`s for this `Product`, I don't want to know each quantity.

Characteristically you have left the property setter `set { //... }` a stub. When adding or changing entities it becomes obvious that the relationship cannot be many-to-many. It is not possible to assign only a list of `RawMaterial`s to a `Product`. You must add the information how many units of each `RawMaterial` to get a valid `Product` model which means that `Product` must be related to the "middle entity" `RecipePart`.

Comment: I absolutely agree with you. That hiding of the middle table is nonsense. It is needed. What I am trying to achieve is something different. I don't want to lose the middle table. I want it. I am trying to have an easy way to manipulate the entrie in B from the entity in A in a way as the middle entity is hidden. 

I repeat,  I do not want to lose the AB entity. I just want to mimic the way as if it was hidden.